# Conditional link behavior in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Couldn't find a proper name for the title, will be glad if someone figures out a better name.

I have a component which represents a product card. The whole component is wrapped in `<router-link>` which leads to product page.

However I have another case, when I do not need the component to lead to a product page, but instead I need to do some other action.

The only solution I found is to pass a callback function as a prop, and based on this, do something like:

```
<router-link v-if="!onClickCallback">
    ... here goes the whole component template ...
</router-link>
<div v-if="onClickCallback" @click="onClickCallback">
    ... here again goes the whole component template ...
</div>
```

How can I do this without copy-pasting the whole component?  I tried to do this (real code sample):

```
  <router-link class="clothing-item-card-preview"
               :class="classes"
               :style="previewStyle"
               :to="{ name: 'clothingItem', params: { id: this.clothingItem.id }}"
               v-on="{ click: onClick ? onClick : null }">
```

However I got this: `Invalid handler for event "click": got null`

Plus not sure if it's possible to pass `prevent` modificator for click and this just looks weird, there should be a better architectural solution

Answer (score 1):

Commenting on the error, you could use an empty function instead of null, in the real code snippet

```
  <router-link class="clothing-item-card-preview"
           :class="classes"
           :style="previewStyle"
           :to="{ name: 'clothingItem', params: { id: this.clothingItem.id }}"
           v-on="{ click: onClick ? onClick : null }">
```

Comment: Yes, but I cannot use ".prevent" in v-on, I guess... so router-link will behave as a link in any case

Answer (score 1):

This should works (replace a for "router-link" then insert right properties)
Further infos :

- https://fr.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html
- v-bind is simply an Object where each keys is a props for your component, so here, I programmatically defined an object of properties depending on the wrapper (router link or a simple div). However we cannot do this for events (of course we could create our own event listener but it's a little bit tricky) so I simply but an handle method.

```js
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
    products : [{onClickCallback : () => { alert("callback"); return true;}}, {}, {}]
    },
    methods : {
        handleClick(product, event) {
            if (!product.onClickCallback) return false
            product.onClickCallback()
            return true
        },
        getMyComponentName(product) {
            if (product.onClickCallback) return "div"
            return "a"
        },

        getMyComponentProperties(product) {
            if (product.onClickCallback) return {is : "div"}
            return {
                is : "a",
                href: "!#"
            }
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <component
        v-for="(product, index) in products"
        :key="index"
        v-bind="getMyComponentProperties(product)"
        @click="handleClick(product, $event)"
    >
        <div class="product-card">
            <div class="product-card-content">
                <span v-show="product.onClickCallback">I'm a callback</span>
                <span v-show="!product.onClickCallback">I'm a router link</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </component>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you *have* to use a `<router-link>`? If it can safely be a `<div>`, you could use something like

```html
<div @click="handleClick" ...>
  <!-- component template -->
</div>
```

and

```js
methods: {
  handleClick (event) {
    if (this.onClickCallback) {
      this.onClickCallback(event)
    } else {
      this.$router.push({ name: 'clothingItem', ... })
    }
  }
}
```

See https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html

Comment: This way user cannot open this product in a new tab. The this is that this has to be a link, so that I can open multiple products in multiple tabs

Comment: @Victor ah, you make an excellent point but what about the other case, where you need the click handler?

Comment: When I need click handler it does not matter if it's a div or link :) But just to be a bit more consistent I'd be using links everywhere